# Flask doesn't show an image

Tags: python, html, flask

So I want to show a diagramm on my HTML page using Flask but when I run my website, then I don't see the image. I know there are a couple of similar questions here, but I'm just stuck with it.

Here is my Python Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('test.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Diagramm</h1>
    <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='test.jpg')}}" alt="Here should be a picture"/>
  </body>

</html>
```

And here is my file path:

```
/home/pi/flask
         /static
                /test.jpg
         /templates
                /test.html
         website.py #This is the Programm
```

Comment: You are missing a slash `/`. It should be `/static`. Could you try this?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing has changed:/

Comment: @ngShravil.py I dont think there should be  "/" , i just ran the OP's example on my end. Picture is rendering fine

Comment: Can you tell us by using the inspect tool in your browser what is the actual src of img that is being generated? @Simon

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot because I have 2 html files and both are called test.html and the programm picked the wrong one. Now everything works fine thank you guys:)@AkibRhast